# Thread.CurrentPrincipal is ClaimsIdentity returns false and how to get the claims from Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have asp.net web application (.NET Framework 4.8), which has ADFS at this point of time for authentication. Now I am working on migration of ADFS authentication to Azure AD with Authorization code flow and OIDC protocol.

I have added a SecurityTokenValidated notification in the OIDC middleware where I am trying to perform validation and add code for custom claim with following code:

```
SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                        {
                           
                            AddUserClaimsToPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);                            

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }

    private void AddUserClaimsToPrincipal(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        string nameClaimValue = string.Empty; // Get Alias
        string emailClaimValue = string.Empty; // Get Email
        string displayClaimNameValue = string.Empty; // Get Display Name
        IPrincipal principal;
        Claim displayNameClaim = identity.FindFirst(t => t.Type == CLAIM_DISPLAYNAME);
        Claim emailClaim = identity.FindFirst(t => t.Type == CLAIM_EMAIL);
        if (displayNameClaim != null)
        {
            displayClaimNameValue = displayNameClaim.Value;
        }

        if (emailClaim != null)
        {
            emailClaimValue = emailClaim.Value;
        }

        nameClaimValue = emailClaimValue;
        List<string> roles;
        bool userExists = ValidateUser(nameClaimValue, out roles);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("SampleApp_UserAuthorized", userExists.ToString()));
        if (identity.FindFirst(t => t.Type == CLAIM_Role) == null)
        {
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(CLAIM_Role, role));
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I am trying to validate the user authorization in Global.asax file using the event : Application_PostAuthenticateRequest

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Thread.CurrentPrincipal is ClaimsIdentity)
  {
     // Code to fetch the claims
     // If the incoming claim contains the custom claim : SampleApp_UserAuthorized then send the user to 
     // unaurhorized.html page
  }
}
```

In the above code I see Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is returning true but on the other hand Thread.CurrentPrincipal is ClaimsIdentity is returning false.

I want to fetch the custom claim:SampleApp_UserAuthorized in the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest to send the user to the unauthorized.html page

Can anyone help me with some code sample to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with the following code and it works fine for me now:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //this.Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            this.Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties{RedirectUri = "/"}, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Thread.CurrentPrincipal is System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)
        {
            if (!Convert.ToBoolean(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal).FindFirst(c => c.Type == "SampleApp_UserAuthorized").Value))
            {
                //Avoid Redirection for static files (used in Access denied page)
                List<string> staticcontentpaths = new List<string>{".css", ".js", ".png", ".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".ico", ".svg", ".woff", ".ttf"};
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath).ToLower();
                if (!staticcontentpaths.Contains(extension))
                {
                    Server.Execute("~/errors/auth.html");
                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }
            }
        }
}
```